# Decode Base-64 image string to bitmap - php

Tags: php, bitmap, base64, encode

I have this php file : UploadToServer.php that decode base 64 an image string and save it as a bitmap image, when I test it with Postman and give it a string, this error popups, I am not very familiar with php.
This is the UploadToServer.php :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST('image_encoded'))) {
    $data = $_POST('image_encoded');
    $file_path = "C:/wamp/www/android_api/Uploads/test.jpg";
    // create a new empty file
    $myfile = fopen($filePath, "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
        // add data to that file
    file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode($data));
}

?>
```

And this is the error :

```
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) 
in C:\wamp\www\android_api\UploadToServer.php on line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$_POST['image_encoded']`. The $_POST identifier **is** actually an array, so the brackets should be square brackets. To test this yourself you could output `print_r($_POST);` once, as you'll never forget it again then.

The code would then become:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['image_encoded'])) {
    $data = $_POST['image_encoded'];
    $file_path = "C:/wamp/www/android_api/Uploads/test.jpg";
    // create a new empty file
    $myfile = fopen($filePath, "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
        // add data to that file
    file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode($data));
}

?>
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand exactly what do you mean, so I have to try this code print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: Oh I see the difference, I'll try it

Comment: In your code you use $_POST('image_encoded') . Normal brackets () are used for function calls. Php interprets this as if you were to call a function $_PHP() { } that you defined somewhere else (which you didn't). Therefore you must use the square brackets [] which are used for arrays, as the $_POST variable is an array.

Comment: It's a minor change but it makes a whole lot of difference. So you should use $_POST['image_encoded'] instead of $_POST('image_encoded')

Answer (score 0):

Look the variable $filePath don't exist, the correct is $file_path:

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['image_encoded'])) {
    $data = $_POST['image_encoded'];
    $file_path = "C:/wamp/www/android_api/Uploads/test.jpg";
    // create a new empty file
    $myfile = fopen($file_path, "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
        // add data to that file
    file_put_contents($file_path, base64_decode($data));
}

?>
```